# Call back function in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

How to write the  call back function for this. I tried different method, but nothing seems working...
I m getting **Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**

```
handleMoveToCart=(item)=>{

        this.moveCart(item, function(){
            this.props.removeFromSaveLater(item.id); //react-redux mapsDispatchToProps function
        });
}

moveCart=(item,callback)=>{
        this.props.moveToCart(item); //react-redux mapsDispatchToProps function

        callback();
}
```

Comment: It's telling you that 'this' is undefined. Need the full file to see why.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind `this` to your function where you want to use `this`.

Add this in constructor

```
this.moveCart = this.moveCart.bind(this);
```

Comment: The problem is with the function passed to `this.moveCart`, not with `this.moveCart` itself.

Answer (score 0):

works fine when replaced **function(){}** with  **()=>**

```
this.moveCart(item, ()=>{
            this.props.removeFromSaveLater(item.id); 
});
```